# How to link color of bar to yticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, colors, bar-chart

I have the datafame below:

[image]

I'd like to do a bar chart for each year, sorted , with one color to each person.
I just got fixed colors, like this:

[image]

[image]

I used this code:

```
color = ['red','blue','green','orange']  
for i in range (2007, 2010):
   fig, ax = plt.subplots()
   x = df2.loc[i,].sort_values()
   y = [x.index[0], x.index[1], x.index[2], x.index[3]]
   ax.barh(y,x, color=color)
   plt.title(i)
```

How can I link colors to names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary linking names to the colors and then use that information while plotting as

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(10, 6))

color = ['red','blue','green','orange']  
colors_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(df2.columns, color)}

for i, ax in zip(range(2007, 2011), axes.flatten()):
    x = df2.loc[i,].sort_values()
    color = [colors_dict[i] for i in x.index]
    ax.barh(x.index, x, color=color)
    ax.set_title(i)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]